# Integrating w.r.t. two different variables

Tags: integration

I can't really follow what's going on here to get from line 2 to line 3:
\begin{align}
& \int^\infty_0 \frac{d^2 p}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{\Lambda^2}{(p^2+\Lambda^2)(p^2+m^2)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \int^1_0 dz \, \frac{d^2 p}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{\Lambda^2}{(p^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2} \\[10pt]
= {} & \int^1_0dz \, \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\Lambda^2}{z\Lambda^2+(1-z)m^2} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\Lambda^2}{\Lambda^2-m^2}\ln\frac{\Lambda^2}{m^2}
\end{align}

There are two different integration variables and then one of them vanishes. I've tried evaluating the integral w.r.t $p$ and then again w.r.t. $p$ because it's $d^2 p$, but that didn't work (just using wolfram alpha).  From line one to line two I can follow, it's a Feynman parametrization, but what do you do to get from line 2 to line 3?

Comment: HINT:  Transform to polar coordinates.

Comment: @jackd'aurizio The OP is referring to the double integral over the momentum variables for which a transformation to polar coordinates was used to arrive at the line in question.

Comment: @MarkViola: In layman's terms, are we looking for $$ \iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)(x^2+y^2+b^2)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\log a^2-\log b^2}{a^2-b^2} $$ ?

Comment: When one writes $\displaystyle \int_a^b \cdots\cdots \, dw,$ then the variable that goes from $a$ to $b$ is $w,$ i.e. the one after the $\text{“}d\text{''}.$ And here we have $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty$ and then $\displaystyle\int_0^1,$ and the question of which variable is in that role of $w$ is present in each case, and its answer is unclear. $\qquad$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : You still have a couple of minutes in which you could edit your comment to say $$\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)(x^2+y^2+b^2)} \text{?}$$ rather than the oddly fomatted punctuation that it now has.

Comment: It seems to be suggested in comments that the first integral is over the quadrant in which two variables are positive. But which two variables? Are they both called $p$ and are we somehow supposed to know which is which? Does the context in which you read this say something that you omitted and that would clarify this?

Comment: @Michaelhardy The notation in the OP is conventional in physics.  The double integral is over momentum space.  A simple transformation to polar coorsinates $(p_1,p_2)\mapsto (\rho, \phi)$, where $p^2=p_1^2+p_2^2\mapsto \rho^2$,facilitates evaluation of the double integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral over momentum space is missing in Line 2 of the OP.  That is to say that the expression $\displaystyle d^2 p\,\frac{\Lambda^2}{(p^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2}$ should read

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\Lambda^2}{(p_1^2+p_2^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2}\,dp_1\,dp_2$$

which after a transformation to polar coordinates $(p_1,p_2)\mapsto(\rho,\phi)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{\Lambda^2}{(p_1^2+p_2^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2}\,dp_1\,dp_2&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\Lambda^2\rho}{(\rho^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2}\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\Lambda^2\rho}{(\rho^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z) m^2)^2}\,\rho\,d\rho\\\\\
&=2\pi \left.\left(-\frac12 \frac{1}{\rho^2+z\Lambda^2+(1-z)m^2}\right)\right|_{\rho=0}^{\rho\to \infty}\\\\
&=2\pi\left(\Lambda^2 \frac12 \frac{1}{z\Lambda^2+(1-z)m^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Finally, dividing by $4\pi^2$ and integrating over $z$ from $0$ to $1$ yields the coveted result.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have got that! How does the technique translate into a 4D integral, like the ones you sometimes get for loop corrections? For 3D you'd have spherical coordinates. Do you change to $\rho^3 \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta_2)d\rho d\theta d\phi d\theta_2$ or similar?

Comment: You're welcome.  For $n$ dimensions, we integrate over the n-sphere.